# How to change language file used by _e function

Tags: multi-language, language

I am trying to make my own language switcher for my WordPress site. I am generating all labels using the `_e` and similar functions. So I am guessing the only thing I need to do is to change the locale used by WordPress. How can I do this programmatically?

So in the ideal scenario when a user clicks on the desired language "this code" is run and WordPress uses the corresponding `.mo` file for the translation.

Comment: Did you try [`switch_to_locale()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/switch_to_locale/) and `restore_previous_locale()`?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need to hook in the 'locale' filter to set the language you want:

```
add_filter('locale', function($locale) {
    return esc_attr($_GET['language']);
});
```

Then in the links of your switch, you need to pass the language variable:

```
<a href="<?php echo add_query_arg('language', 'xx_XX') ?>">XX</a>
```

Where xx_XX is the language locale code for language XX

Comment: Thanks! I also tried changing the global $locale variable. It worked too!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @maxime's answer, I found that the following method worked too. Simply change the `$locale` global variable. This will fix most translations. If you want to specify the locale for specific text domains, then simply call the `load_textdomain()` function pointing to the appropriate `.mo` file.

```
$locale = 'en_US';

if ( file_exists( WP_LANG_DIR . '/' . $locale . '.mo' ) ) {
    load_textdomain( 'my_domain', WP_LANG_DIR . '/' . $locale . '.mo' );
}
```

Now, in the above example, if your `languages` folder contains the file `en_US.mo`, you're good to go.

So when you call something like,

```
echo _e('Hello', 'my_domain');
```

the appropriate translations in your associated `.po` file will be reflected.

You can find a detailed explanation at https://codex.buddypress.org/getting-started/customizing/customizing-labels-messages-and-urls/.

This is intended for BuddyPress, but the idea applies generally.