# where to add this filter? in which file should be added?

Tags: multi-language, language

For wordpress language switcher, this post was helpful for others, but I don't know where to add the mentioned filter

[How to change language file used by _e function](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/260096)

```
add_filter('locale', function($locale) {
    return esc_attr($_GET['language']);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code to your functions.php file in your WordPress theme files.

See this article for some additional help:
https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-add-code-to-functions-php-in-wordpress/